# Robotium-ClickOnView(solo.getView(id)) is not working on a widget layout

Tags: android, android-layout, robotium

1. Launched the Android application through automation script, and waits until the main activity is launched, clicks on a link for which an overlay appears
2. On this overlay I have tried almost everything to click on a element, using `clickOnView`, `clickOnButtonById` , `clickLongOnText`, `clickOnButton`, `clickOnScreen`, `clickOnText`, but nothing is working. Is there any issue with clicking on elements on overlay

I have also tried below code

```
LinearLayout submitBtn = (LinearLayout) solo.getView(id);
assertNotNull(submitBtn);
submitBtn.performClick();
```

and

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) solo.getView(R.id.x);
solo.clickOnView(imageButton);
```

but nothing works

Used code `solo.clickLongOnText("text", 1, false);` to avoid scroll but this is also not identifying the element

I have tried with text view and id of the element but nothing works.

It is Android 4.4.2 platform and emulator is Nexus 5

I cannot share the details of the application.

If any one has come across the same issue and got any solution, please post here, it would be helpful....

Comment: What do you mean by overlay?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with solo.getCurrentActivity().getView(id)